# Linting not working for Typescript 3.7 in tslint Angular 9

Tags: angular, typescript, tslint

I upgraded to Angular version 9 which comes with Typescript 3.7. I use tslint and my linting isn't recognizing new features such as optional chaining or null coalescing. Do I need to switch to eslint, or is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see they fixed it into 6.0.0beta version [lint](https://github.com/palantir/tslint/releases/tag/6.0.0-beta0). The official migration to ESlint will be in angular10 [source](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/13732)